# Is it able to create a sub object from a parent object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I want to create an object with another class object as parent. For example:

```
class Parent:
    value = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = int(input())
        self.call_subclass()

    def call_subclass(self):
        self.sub = Child()

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.value)

obj = Parent()
```

Let's say the input is `3`, my expected output of print is also `3`. But the actual output of above code is `0`. The point is that, I want the sub class to inherit the *self* object of Parent. Not only inheriting the method and class variable from the Parent class, but also those instance variables of an actual called and existed Parent class object.

I know that there is a way to do this, is like below:

```
class Parent:
    value = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = int(input())
        self.call_subclass()

    def call_subclass(self):
        self.sub = Child(self.value)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        print(self.value)

obj = Parent()
```

But this will be so clumsy if there is many instance variable. Also, the value is passing to Child by value, but not reference. So Child cannot get the most update instance variable value from Parent, but is what I want it to be able to implement.

Also, I know there is another way as below:

```
class Parent:
    value = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = int(input())
        self.call_subclass()

    def call_subclass(self):
        self.sub = Child(self)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        print(self.parent.value)

obj = Parent()
```

But this way seems not so concise. Also, some redundant resource will be produced, for example the Parent class' variable `value = 0` will be inherited but with no use(the Child class should only interest in the instance variable and method of Parent class object `obj`). I would like to know if there is better method to achieve my purpose.

I understand there should be somebody already ask similar question, but I don't know what's the name of this technic. Therefore, I cannot find related information and decide to ask.

Comment: I feel that it would be useful to know a bit about the purpose here. How is `Child` different from `Parent` if it inherits its method and has exactly the same instance variables? Why do we _need_ `Child`? Also, is there one `Parent` globally, or are there many?

Comment: I found a better way to explain my objective. In other word, I am trying to construct child object from parent reference. For instance, `Parent` object represent a social media account and contains the info. of the account. The `Child` objects represent the posts that an account have been posted. So those `Child`s should share same `Parent` object. And the reason of using `Child` class is because of the data structure. And globally, there maybe more than one `Parent`.

Comment: It looks like you have a serious misunderstanding about classes. Inheritance means that *every* ``Child`` is *also* a fully functional ``Parent`` – by creating a sub object you already create a parent object from it, not the other way around. Also, inheritance is something that happens between *classes*, not instances, so inheriting "those instance variables" just makes no sense. Those are the two major features of inheritance, and the design seems to use both wrong. Instead of looking to make this broken design more comfortable, it would be better to ask about your *actual* problem.

Comment: You are right. After research more deeply about classes, I found that the function of classes is not really design for this purpose. And I notice that this is not a good question. By the way, to achieve the above purpose, I now use the way of passing `self` to `Class` objects. Similar to the one which @VedranŠego provided and the 3rd code in my question.

Comment: @HuiGordon, one thing I dropped silently, but I should probably bring your attention to it: `value = 0` is initialising class variable `value`, while `self.value = ...` is an instance one. These are two different variable, with the instance one kinda hiding the class one. In other words, `value = 0` is not a good way to initialise this.

Comment: I see, thanks for reminding. Then I should bring the class variable `value` under `def __init__(self):`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment, I'd say you need something like this:

```py
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = int(input())

class Child:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._parent = parent

    def print_value(self)
        print(self._parent.value)

parent = Parent()  # input a number, for example 17

child1 = Child(parent)
child1.print_value()  # print 17
child2 = Child(parent)
child2.print_value()  # print 17

parent.value = 19
child1.print_value()  # print 19
child2.print_value()  # print 19
```

It is unclear what `call_subclass` would do. If you want to call something from all children of a parent, then

```py
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = int(input())
        self._children = list()

    def register_child(self, child):
        self._children.append(child)

    def call_children_f(self, foo):
        for child in self._children:
            child.f(foo)

class Child:
    def __init__(self, parent, x):
        self._parent = parent
        self.x = x
        self._parent.register_child(self)

    def print_value(self)
        print(self._parent.value)

    def f(self, foo):
        print(f"Parent: {self._parent.value}, foo: {foo}, x: {self.x}")

parent = Parent()  # input a number, for example 17

child1 = Child(parent, 19)
child2 = Child(parent, 23)

parent.call_children_f(29)
```

This will print:

```
Parent: 17, foo: 29, x: 19
Parent: 17, foo: 29, x: 23
```

Comment: I just removed inheritance from `Child`. It was a left-over from copy/pasting your base code. `Child` should not inherit `Parent` here because `Child` *is not* a `Parent`. Instead, it *has* a `Parent`, and that's not done via inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

if I am understanding correctly, I think you should just instance a `Child` class and not a `Parent` class.

Change the last line (from the original code) to this:

```py
obj = Child()
```

Comment: I understand what you mean. So I should call super.__init__() in this way. But since I may want to define more than one Child object in the Parent methods. And I want them to share the instant variable of same Parent obj. If I use this method, each Child obj will have their own Parent object.